# Color siblings above and below a hovered element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In HTML, I have an ordered list with some list items. When hovering, an item I want that all items below it to become blue and all items above (including the hovered one) to become red.

I was able to do the first part, but not the second part. Thank you!

```css
ol li:hover~li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: No, because its list items were already one of the colors. Mine are default black.

Comment: the duplicate details all the technique and the one used below are also there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination of CSS rules (in this exact order) should do what you want:

```css
ol:hover {
  color: red;
}

ol li:hover ~ li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: (including the hovered one) to become red.

Comment: yes, I overread that initially and just changed it.

Comment: Now, similar to Sandrin Joy's answer

Comment: no, the order is the other way round, and it omits `!important`

Comment: btw thanks for this information :)

Answer (score 1):

**Well , there is no proper way to select the previously present children in css.**

*what we can do is our own simple, creative tricks*

```css
ol li:hover~li {
  color: blue ;
}
ol:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```